# delegate method does not get called second time

Tags: swift, xcode, delegates, protocols

I am building a simple currency converter app. When `ViewController` gets opened it calls a function from `CoinManager.swift`:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var coinManager = CoinManager()

        override func viewDidLoad() {
           super.viewDidLoad()
            
            coinManager.delegate = self
            coinManager.getCoinPrice(for: "AUD", "AZN", firstCall: true)
        }
...
}
```

CoinManager.swift:

```
protocol CoinManagerDelegate {
    func didUpdatePrice(price1: Double, currency1: String, price2: Double, currency2: String)
    func tellTableView(descriptions: [String], symbols: [String])
    func didFailWithError(error: Error)
}

struct CoinManager {

    var delegate: CoinManagerDelegate?
    let baseURL = "https://www.cbr-xml-daily.ru/daily_json.js"

    func getCoinPrice (for currency1: String,_ currency2: String, firstCall: Bool) {

        if let url = URL(string: baseURL) {

            let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)
            let task = session.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
                if error != nil {
                    self.delegate?.didFailWithError(error: error!)
                    return
                }

                if let safeData = data {
                    if let coinData = self.parseJSON(safeData) {
                        
                        if firstCall {
                            var descriptions = [""]
                            let listOfCoins = Array(coinData.keys)
                            
                            for key in listOfCoins {
                                descriptions.append(coinData[key]!.Name)
                            }
                            descriptions.removeFirst()
                            self.delegate?.tellTableView(descriptions: descriptions, symbols: listOfCoins)
                        }

                        if let coinInfo1 = coinData[currency1] {
                            let value1 = coinInfo1.Value
                            if let coinInfo2 = coinData[currency2] {
                                let value2 = coinInfo2.Value

//this line does not do anything the second time I call getCoinPrice: 
                                self.delegate?.didUpdatePrice(price1: value1, currency1: currency1, price2: value2, currency2: currency2) 
//And this one does work
                                print("delegate:\(currency1)") 
                            } else {
                                print("no name matches currency2")
                            }
                        } else {
                            print("no name matches currency1")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            task.resume()
        }
    }
func ParseJSON....
}
```

The method it calls (ViewController.swift):

```
extension ViewController: CoinManagerDelegate {

    func didUpdatePrice(price1: Double, currency1: String, price2: Double, currency2: String) {
        
        print("didUpdatePrice called")
        
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            let price1AsString = String(price1)
            let price2AsString = String(price2)
            self.leftTextField.text = price1AsString
            self.rightTextField.text = price2AsString
            self.leftLabel.text = currency1
            self.rightLabel.text = currency2
        }
    }
...
}
```

and finally, CurrencyViewController.swift:

```
var coinManager = CoinManager()

   @IBAction func backButtonPressed(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        coinManager.getCoinPrice(for: "USD", "AZN", firstCall: false)
    }
```

So when I launch the app i get following in my debug console:

```
didUpdatePrice called
delegate:AUD
```

And when I call `getCoinPrice()` from `CurrencyViewController` the delegate method does not get called. I know that my code goes through the delegate function line as I get this in debug console:

```
delegate:USD
```

I just can't wrap my head around it. The delegate method does not work when gets called second time. Even though it is called by the same algorithm

Comment: Saying 'this line doesn't work' is vague. Do you mean that line doesn't cause prints to happen fro your `didUpdatePrice` function? If so did you breakpoint at that line? Did you check to see if the `delegate` is `nil` the 2nd time?

Comment: how would i do that?

Comment: What [this Stanford video on debugging](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CRxHhx_pubY). It goes over all the good things

Comment: Pass coinManager to CurrencyViewController.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because you're creating a new object of `CoinManager` in `CurrencyViewController` where the `delegate` is not set. So you've to set the `delegate` every time you create a new instance of `CoinManager`.

```
@IBAction func backButtonPressed(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    coinManager.delegate = self
    coinManager.getCoinPrice(for: "USD", "AZN", firstCall: false)
}
```

Update: So, the above solution would require for you to make the delegate conformance in `CurrencyViewController`. If you're looking for an alternate solution you should probably pass the instance of `coinManager` in `ViewController` to `CurrencyViewController`. For that here are the things you need to update.

In `CurrencyViewController`:

```
class CurrencyViewController: UIViewController {
    var coinManager: CoinManager! // you can optional unwrap if you intent to use CurrencyViewController without coinManager
    //...
```

And in `ViewController`:

```
currencyViewController.coinManager = coinManager // passing the instance of coinManager
```

Comment: I didn't see here the creation of a new instance. Instance only created on viewDidLoad as I see and delegate added also only once on viewDidLoad

Comment: it is outside of IBAction. I think this a global variable. So here we have only 1 instance of coin manager.

Comment: if I do that, I have to add protocol stubs to CurrencyViewController and redefine the delegate functions

Comment: Either that or give the `ViewController` a callback to make this call or pass the instance of `CoinManager` in `ViewController` to `CurrencyViewController`.

Comment: Passing coinManager did help! Thank you so much!

Comment: Earlier you had 2 different coinManagers. One have a delegate, another - didn't have

Answer (score 0):

Can you share the full code of CoinManager? I see this part

```
if firstCall {
  ...
}
```

Maybe some block logic here or unhandled cases? And can you share the full code of protocol?

Also try to print something before this code:

```
if error != nil {
    self.delegate?.didFailWithError(error: error!)
        return
}
```

Comment: I added the info. Also I added the print line you told me to: `made past URL,   
didUpdatePrice called,      
delegate:AUD,   
made past URL,   
delegate:USD`

Comment: How many times in ViewController did you instantiate a new coin manager? like this: var coinManage = Coin Manager()

Comment: one time in ViewController, one time in CurrencyViewController

Comment: You can print "self.delegate" below the line when it doesn't call in the second time. You need to make sure that it is not nil in second time. So print("delegate \(self.delegate)") instead of print("delegate:\(currency1)")

Comment: It is nil. How come?

Comment: Can you share code when you are opening a second controller? so you need to create a coinManager in second controller and set it each team when second controller opens.